# module 'hnswlib' has no attribute 'Index'

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, search

I downloaded hnswlib package to my env but I am constantly getting an error about
AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
in
1 # Declaring index
----> 2 p = hnswlib.Index(space = 'cosine', dim = EMBEDDING_SIZE) # possible options are l2, cosine or ip

AttributeError: module 'hnswlib' has no attribute 'Index'
changing env didn't help

Comment: What is your operating system and virtual env Python version?

Comment: Linux, python 3.7, I am running in conda env